# How can I change the title of the site on Google search?

Tags: 7

I have changed the site name to *HoNESt*, but when I search for the website on Google, the site name results *HoNESt: Front Page*.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Meta Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag)

> The Metatag module allows you to automatically provide structured
> metadata, aka "meta tags", about a website. In the context of search
> engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags they are usually
> referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords tag that
> may help improve the rankings and display of a site in search engine
> results.

**Basically it allows you to format your title and description that gets indexed by search engines.**

Once you install it, you need to override the Global: Front Page and remove the [site:name] token.

Here is a [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SviVqtAinSk)

**PS**: You will need to wait until Google crawls your site again to see changes.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I installed Metatag module and override the title, but nothing seems to change on Google search. Maybe is a cache problem?

Comment: read my **PS:** part.

Comment: it could take days, it depends how popular your site is.

Comment: If you are using Google Webmaster tools account you can tell google to re-crawl it. If you don't have one, you can sign up for one. **[How to request Google to re-crawl my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466360/how-to-request-google-to-re-crawl-my-website)**